# Обращение к компонентам формы

Tags: c#

Как обратиться к компонентам другой формы? Например, из формы 1 к тексбоксу на форме 2.

```
 Form2 testDialog = new Form2();
 testDialog.Text = "Редактирование записи";
 testDialog.textBox1.text = ""; // Эта строка не работает как надо, не передает данные.
 testDialog.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот: [передача данных между формами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/98422/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=98845#98845).