# Как правильно передавать данные между формами?

Tags: c#, winforms

Искал вопрос в инете на данную тему, много вариантов, но про правильный нигде не сказано. Больше всего скланяюсь к этому варианту: [Передача данных между формами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/98422/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).
Можете подсказать начинающему, как правильно передавать данные между формами. Будет здорово если посоветуете хорошую книгу по C# с примерами.

Для примера копирование из одного `textBox` в другой:

`Form1` с `textBoxOfForm1`, `buttonOfForm1` и `Form2` с `textBoxOfForm2`. Записали в текст в `textBoxOfForm1` далее нажимаем на `buttonOfForm1` и текст должен появиться в `textBoxOfForm2`.

Comment: большой и спорный вопрос, зависит от конкретного проекта и что вы хотите получить, можно использовать делегаты, объявлять входящие переменные в конструкторе второй формы, использовать вторую форму в виде диалогового окна, использовать внешние глобальные классы и т.д.

Comment: Я хочу получить результат не нарушающий логики и принципов ООП. Вариант, который будет верным с точки зрения ООП, и не будет являться кривым костылем. Как-то так.

Comment: Форма такой же объект, и описывается ровно таким же, как все другие, классом. Если вы понимаете принципы ООП, то просто соблюдайте их в коде, а передача данных между формами ни чем не отличается от передачи данных между любыми другими объектами. Выбор конкретного метода зависит исключительно от решаемой задачи и общей архитектуры проекта.

Comment: По поводу литературы, смотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/198316

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на литературу. Из полученных комментариев к моему посту, я понял, что определенного способа нет. Ну будем стараться не нарушать логику ООП и пилить хорошие приложения. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

MVP паттерн -конкретно для WinForms.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/69257)

Comment: А какие тут могут  быть  поправки. Это конкретный ответ на заданный вопрос. Для Win forms  -MVP паттерн это средство не нарушающее принципы и логику OOП(по моему мнению).Программа разбивается на 3 части:Model, View, Presenter. Model - сама логика программы, View -набор форм, Presenter - набор классов (класс) пересылающий данные между формами и моделью.Для его реализации используются делегаты и события языка С#.

Comment: Вот эту информацию стоило бы добавить в ответ.