# Имеется две формы. Как взять содержимое TextBox из первой формы и передать во вторую?

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется две формы. Как взять содержимое TextBox из первой формы и передать во вторую? 
https://github.com/Drein211/test-for-the-personnel-department-prefecture-SZAO здесь можно посмотреть на то что есть сейчас (Нужно передать значение TBLastName)

Comment: А что мешает взять и присвоить?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/98422/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходники не смотрел, но можно сделать так:

1. Для второй формы сделать дополнительный конструктор, который будет принимать строку.
2. Во второй форме сделать открытый метод и передать туда значение после создания второй формы.

Answer (score 1):

Создать сингелтон так называемый.

```
class Singleton
  {
      private static Singleton instance;
      private Singleton()
          {}
      public string TBLastName="";
      public static Singleton getInstance()
          {
                if (instance == null)
                  instance = new Singleton();
                return instance;
          }
  }
```

И можно к этому делу обращаться из любой формы.
В модулях форм обоих надо добавить using этого класса.
И переменную к которой обращаться.

```
using MyApp.Singelton
...
private Singelton globalTBLastName;
```

Получить в форме 2

```
    {
     textBox1.Text=globalTBLastName.getINstance().TBLastName;
    }
```

Присвоить в форме1

```
    {
     globalTBLastName.getINstance().TBLastName=textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: если формы работают одновременно, на форме которая принимает поставить таймер, и дергать там  textBox1.Text=globalTBLastName.getINstance().TBLastName;