# Передача данных из UserControl в другую форму

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

В UserControl есть Textbox,в нём есть текст. Этот текст нужно передать в другой TextBox в новой форме

Из другого класса пытаюсь показать текст из TextBox'a ( который находится в  UserControl )

В UserControl в поле TextBox'a выставил Public доступ ( чтобы можно было из формы достучаться до TextBox'a )

```
MyUserControl PC = new MyUserControl();
TextBox.Text = PC.NameTextBox.Text);
```

Но текст не показывается.

Как вывести текст из UserControl в TextBox другой формы?

Comment: А как `UserControl` добавляется на форму (или где он отображается)?

Comment: Прочитай тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/98422/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: @defaultlocale, `MyUserControl PC = new MyUserControl();` и с него читаю данные: `PC.NameTextBox.Text`

Comment: @Дмитрий Так он создается. А где он отображается? Если добавили его на форму в дизайнере, то поищите в свойствах имя (Name) компонента.

Comment: Идея правильная, хотя обычно вместо прямого доступа к элементам делают проброс свойства `public string Text { get { return textBox1.Text; } }`. Видимо где-то ошиблись с реализацией и на момент обращения текст пустой: к примеру код выполняется до заполнения поля текстом в контроле.

Comment: @AlexKrass, Получить текст получилось, спс.

Comment: @Дмитрий правильнее всего использовать для подобного вазимодействия шареный контекст - модельный класс, который создаётся один раз и передаётся в конструктор каждой формы, через него и организуется обмен данными. В WinForms наибольшее распространение получил паттер MVC. В WPF - MVVM(C)

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант можно извращатся и сделать так

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var T = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.OfType<Panel>().FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == "panel1").Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().FirstOrDefault();
            var y = T.Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault().Text;
            MessageBox.Show(y);
        }
```

При загрузке формы 2 берем текст Label из UserControl c Form1

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821536/c-winforms-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0/821567#821567), на примере передачи значения TrackBar в реальном времени.

Comment: на ответ не тянет. это либо комментарий к вопросу, либо предложение закрыть данный вопрос как дубликат указанного. за что голосовать? за дубликат или за преобразование в комментарий?