# c# winforms получить значение из нового окна

Tags: c#, winforms

есть 2 формы. на первой, допустим, кнопка открывающая 2-ю форму, на которой есть ползунок TrackBar. как при каждом изменении значения ползунка передавать его значение в главное окно?
Пробовал такой вариант:
**form1.cs**

```
private void openTrackbar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (form2 f2 = new form2())
    {
        if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int o = Int32.Parse(f2.trackbarValue);
            MessageBox.Show(o + "");
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }

}
```

**form2.cs**

```
public string trackbarValue {
    get { return opacityTrackbar.Value.ToString(); }
}
```

срабатывает только при закрытии 2й формы и выдает "error"

Comment: Вы можете подписаться на событие "изменение значение ползунка" и получать его в основной форме.

Comment: Не могли бы ссылку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая форма

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form2.TrackBarScrollEvent += Form2_TrackBarScrollEventt;

private void Form2_TrackBarScrollEventt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TrackBar trackBar = sender as TrackBar;
    if (trackBar == null) return;
        string message = trackBar.Value.ToString();
}
```

Вторая форма с элементом управления **TrackBar**

```
public event EventHandler TrackBarScrollEvent;
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TrackBarScrollEvent?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: TrackBarScrollEvent?. - этот вопр. знак точно там нужен? у меня ошибка, без него работает

Comment: @axmed2004 знак вопроса - это [Оператор условного null](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.26.php). В данном случае применяется для того, чтобы предотвратить вызов события если не него нет "подписантов".

Comment: @axmed2004 Возможно вы используете не 2017 VS.